# "overflow-x:hidden" one side only?

Tags: jquery, html, css

Is it possible to hide the horizontal overflow of an element on one side only: left or right? Something like `overflow-x-right:hidden;`. I am open to css and jquery based tips.

Comment: Many answers assume this only applies to making text overflow from the left side of the div. This would actually be useful for things like clipping the box-shadow only on the left side.

Answer (score 25):

This is how you could do it using `clip-path`, which replaced the deprecated `clip` property:

```css
.outer {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,255,.5);
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 100px;
  clip-path: inset( -100vw -100vw -100vw 0 );
}

.inner {
  background-color: rgba(255,0,0,.5);
  width: 200px;
  height: 80px;
  position: relative;
  top: 10px;
  left: -50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
```

Note that, as of December 2017, [browser support isn't very good](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-clip-path).

Further reading:

- [MDN: `clip-path`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path)
- [CSS-Tricks: `clip-path`](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/c/clip/)

Comment: Indeed, it cuts the contents. but contents still take space, which may lead to unwanted layout. In overflow:hidden, content wont take any space

Answer (score 11):

All content starts on the left, unless otherwise defined. So if you want content on the left to be hidden, consider making the element `position: absolute`, and setting it to `right: 0`. Combine that with `overflow-x: hidden`, which should accomplish your goal.

Comment: It doesn't have to be absolutely positioned, use any way of pushing the content up against the right of the parent element, set a width and overflow-x:hidden and it will effectively hide the left as requested.

Answer (score 7):

If CSS3 is a option, "clip" is definitely your solution.

http://www.css3.com/css-clip/

Comment: Actually, this is already available since CSS 2.1. It is even supported by IE 6+, as long as you don't use commas (and just use spaces). 

So clip is an excellent solution for this problem!

Comment: cheers, didn't know that. those guys really push it hard to make CSS cross browser the biggest mess, and they do it really well.

Comment: From MDN: *Warning: This property is deprecated. Use **clip-path** instead.*  `clip-path`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path

Answer (score 3):

When you say **Horizontal**, then we only have *one* side bar, and that is at the bottom of the container. So, technically there is no *left* or *right* for that. For **vertical** scrolls, the `direction` attribute of the container, or parents, determine whether it's located on right, or on left.

That's all you can do, with normal CSS, and ordinary browser UI. Otherwise, you should create your own controls and UI widgets.