# CSS - How to make overflow hidden on the right but not the left?

Tags: jquery, css, scroll, overflow, containers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“overflow-x:hidden” one side only?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8953971/overflow-xhidden-one-side-only)

I have a container that scrolls horizontally and when the user scrolls to the left and it overflows out I want it to still show, but any time the user scrolls to the right, I want it to hide. Any suggestions?

Here's some code:

```
<div class="scroller">
    ... content
</div>
```

---

```
.scroller {
    overflow-x: scroll;
}
```

Comment: Your question has been answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8953971/overflow-xhidden-one-side-only) on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In div content always starts from left to right, so make your div `position:absolute` and  `left:0;` then use `overflow-x: hidden;` this styles only apply left side to be hide

```
.scroller {
   overflow-x: hidden;
   position:absolute;
   left:0;
}
```